# Google Webmaster Tools says average position 2.4 but no clicks

Tags: seo

There is a page on my website that gets the most impressions according to webmaster  tools with an average position of 2.4 but I am  not getting any clicks. I have worked out that the position is calculated as 2.4 because they display an image from that page. However, they do not show the text link to that page at any level as far as I can see. So I don't get any clicks because the text link is absent. I would appreciate any help in how I can get the text link to show.

The keyword phrase to use is "cup and handle pattern" and my image is the fourth one under "images for cup and handle pattern" which links to my site.

I have worked on the page meta description and keywords quite extensively over the last three months but have not had any success in getting the text link to appear.

Comment: If GWT is telling you that the average position is 2.4, that is the average position for your *page* in the SERPs for the queries where your *page* had an impression in the SERPs. It is not uncommon that pages with high positions not to convert. Stop messing with the page you will only make things worse. Make sure that your link and snippet in the SERPs is compelling. Otherwise no-one will click on it. Get back to the basics of SEO. The keywords meta-tag has no value. Title tag and description, if done well, will help to convert impressions into clicks. Placing high in he SERPs is no lock.

Comment: @dan I could not help myself and answered this one. I know that it is about one site, but this poor guy would have been lost forever. Should we edit the question and re-open it? Or are there other issues?

Comment: @closetnoc I'm not sure how to edit this to be applicable to others in the future - it's also a bit unclear and too broad (e.g., "how I can get the text link to show"). Please feel free to edit it though, that's always helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

If Google Webmaster Tools is telling you that the average position is 2.4, that is the average position for your page in the SERPs for the queries where your page had an impression in the SERPs. It is not uncommon that pages with high positions not to convert. The image bar you are seeing has nothing to do with your performance.

I did a search using your keywords in quotes as you have provided them. You are not in the top 20. I also visited your page. You are up against some tough competition with well established reputations and time in service. You have an up-hill battle, but all is not lost. You can still compete and compete well.

Stop messing with the page you will only make things worse. The more you change the page, the more Google has to fetch the page, re-index it, and formulate any metrics for the page. In other words, the more you mess with it, the more you delay any positive outcome. Leave it alone except for the changes I recommend below.

There are a few things you have to make sure you do. First off, get links to that page even if it is just a few. Try and get any buddies in academia to link from their personal page on the university site if you can or from their business sites or personal sites. Secondly, make the `title` tag compelling so that the search engine results page (SERP) link will entice people to click. Third, shorten the `description` tag so that it fits into the snippet portion of any SERP listing. Shoot for two to three lines tops but not one. Fourth, your page does not have an `h1` tag. Change your "Cup and Handle Pattern Watchlist Methodology" to an `h1` tag and then adjust it as described later. Make sure that the `title` tag has your most important 2-3 keywords for that page. More is fine too. Make sure that your `h1` tag supports the `title` tag keywords and possibly adds 1-2 more important keywords but is not a duplicate of the `title` tag. Your `description` tag should support your `title` tag and `h1` tag even though it does not carry keyword weight. It will however, support search results. Remove the inline CSS style and move it to an external file. As well, if possible, move the JavaScript to the end of the page. These last two items are not deal-breakers, but could help. If you leave them, it would not matter for now.

Make sure that your link and snippet in the SERPs are compelling. Otherwise no-one will click on your link. Get back to the basics of SEO. The `keywords` meta-tag has no value. You can drop it entirely. The `title` tag and `description`, if done well, will help to convert impressions into clicks. Placing high in he SERPs is no guarantee of success. Conversion is the key.

It looks like you are using tools to create your page that may not be helping you to create a page that will perform well. This page as it stands should not perform well at all. If it was not for the niche nature of the topic, this page would get lost in the vast ocean of content. And that is actually good news. Imagine if this page did perform well. Being in a niche content market is gold trust me.

I do not mean to be brutal. Just constructive and direct.

Your content looks to be excellent. Your site is simple and well decorated. You have already done well. Study SEO the best that you can, but I warn you that most of what you will read online is junk. Go with the very simple basics and ignore the tricks. Here is a good place to start: http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo and when you have questions, come here. Even if you don't have questions, come here. We will be glad to help sort out the truth from the hype.

Comment: Thanks for answering although it was deemed off topic. I hadn't expected such a prompt or detailed answer. I'll work on your suggestions.

Comment: @user1142052 My pleasure. I did not want you going round and round again when the answer was as easy as it was. I do like your site. It is neat and clean and informative in the way I am used to making sites. You should do rather well with people. Your site exudes trust and honesty. Come back when you have questions. I am here every night and generally late morning to early afternoon.